# Does Groovy follow Tennent's Correspondence Principle?

Tags: language-design, groovy, closures

[Here's an interesting discussion of Tennent's Correspondence Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116395/what-is-the-good-explanation-of-tennents-correspondence-principle), and a brief description from [Neal Gafter](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/08/tennents-correspondence-principle-and.html):

> The principle dictates that an expression or statement, when wrapped in a closure and then immediately invoked, ought to have the same meaning as it did before being wrapped in a closure. Any change in semantics when wrapping code in a closure is likely a flaw in the language.

Does the Groovy language follow this principle?

Answer (score 4):

Not quite, but almost.  All the variables accessible in the outer scope are accessible in the closure, including 'this' and class data members.  However, a `return` statement returns from the closure, not from the enclosing function.  I'm not even sure that is a violation of TCP; I don't know of any C-style language where `return` in a closure returns from the enclosing scope.  I have had no surprises using Groovy closures.

Comment: Would be -1 if I had sufficient rep, see further in the link from OP: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/116395/what-is-the-good-explanation-of-tennents-correspondence-principle#120409